# Error -- KIO Client Could not connect to host ... SSL negotiation failed

Tags: firefox, ssl, wine, plasma5, playonlinux

An alternate title might be:

```
PlayOnLinux LOTRO install: Open Store In External Browser Fails
```

This question concerns a Linux installation of Lord Of The Rings Online using Wine 5.2 in a PlayOnLinux virtual drive in a KDE Plasma desktop.  The host system is a 64-bit Mageia 7 installation.  The game is generally rock solid, and the in-game store is usable, but only if opened in an external browser rather than the in-game browser.  The only GUI browser installed is FireFox.

Normally, clicking the in-game LOTRO Store link auto-opens FireFox in an authenticated session that is automatically linked with the LOTRO account being played at the time.  This has worked for years.

All of a sudden, but probably after system/browser updates, the LOTRO Store no longer opens, and instead, a dialog pops up:

```
                        Error -- KIO Client

[X] Could not connect to host www.lotro.com: SSL negotiation failed.

                                                              [ OK ]
```

Restarting the game client, restarting FireFox, and restarting the computer do not have any
positive effect.  It is not clear how to troubleshoot or correct this issue.

Digging returns:

```
# journalctl -xe | grep -i KIO
Oct 08 22:56:03 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: Could not find service for job "Job 1" with app name "org.kde.kioclient"
Oct 08 22:56:03 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: Could not find service for job "Job 1" with app name "org.kde.kioclient"
Oct 08 22:56:25 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: Could not find service for job "Job 2" with app name "org.kde.kioclient"
Oct 08 22:56:25 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: Could not find service for job "Job 2" with app name "org.kde.kioclient"
Oct 08 22:56:25 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: Could not find service for job "Job 2" with app name "org.kde.kioclient"
Oct 08 22:56:25 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: Could not find service for job "Job 2" with app name "org.kde.kioclient"
Oct 08 22:58:23 obfuscated.domain.tld kde-open5[27904]: kf5.kio.widgets: KRun(0x68b600) ERROR (stat): 123   "Could not connect to host www.lotro.com: SSL negotiation failed."
Oct 08 23:01:17 obfuscated.domain.tld kde-open5[9450]: kf5.kio.widgets: KRun(0xd25570) ERROR (stat): 123   "Could not connect to host www.lotro.com: SSL negotiation failed."
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: Could not find service for job "Job 5" with app name "org.kde.kioclient"
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld kde-open5[7327]: kf5.kio.widgets: KRun(0xa5e3f0) ERROR (stat): 123   "Could not connect to host www.lotro.com: SSL negotiation failed."
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: Could not find service for job "Job 5" with app name "org.kde.kioclient"
Oct 08 23:09:31 obfuscated.domain.tld kde-open5[17589]: kf5.kio.widgets: KRun(0x198a4b0) ERROR (stat): 123   "Could not connect to host www.lotro.com: SSL negotiation failed."
```

The cluster of errors around the obvious `www.lotro.com` failure looks like:

```
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: Could not find service for job "Job 5" with app name "org.kde.kioclient"
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:99: TypeError: Type error
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:99: TypeError: Type error
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:99: TypeError: Type error
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld kde-open5[7327]: kf5.kio.widgets: KRun(0xa5e3f0) ERROR (stat): 123   "Could not connect to host www.lotro.com: SSL negotiation failed."
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: Could not find service for job "Job 5" with app name "org.kde.kioclient"
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ScrollView.qml:362: TypeError: Type error
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ScrollView.qml:363: TypeError: Type error
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ScrollView.qml:364: TypeError: Type error
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ScrollView.qml:365: TypeError: Type error
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:99: TypeError: Type error
Oct 08 23:07:24 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:99: TypeError: Type error
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36601, resource id: 113246214, major code: 19 (DeleteProperty), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36604, resource id: 113246214, major code: 19 (DeleteProperty), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36605, resource id: 113246214, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36606, resource id: 113246214, major code: 19 (DeleteProperty), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36607, resource id: 113246214, major code: 19 (DeleteProperty), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36608, resource id: 113246214, major code: 19 (DeleteProperty), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld.net kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36609, resource id: 113246214, major code: 7 (ReparentWindow), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36610, resource id: 113246214, major code: 6 (ChangeSaveSet), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36611, resource id: 113246214, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36612, resource id: 113246214, major code: 10 (UnmapWindow), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 36680, resource id: 113246224, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:32 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 9665, resource id: 113246214, major code: 141 (Unknown), minor code: 3
Oct 08 23:07:34 obfuscated.domain.tld kwin_x11[10271]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 38362, resource id: 83886096, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
Oct 08 23:07:35 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 9879, resource id: 83886086, major code: 141 (Unknown), minor code: 3
Oct 08 23:07:35 obfuscated.domain.tld plasmashell[10275]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 150 (Unknown), sequence: 9880, resource id: 35651797, major code: 142 (Unknown), minor code: 2
```

It seems unlikely this this is a LOTRO game client issue.  For the most part, as long as I can remember, game client updates do not affect stability or usability of the game.  A raft of OS updates was applied within the past week or so, but as one does not necessarily open the store every time one plays it could be a bit difficult to pin down what might have changed at the time it stopped working.

I started posting this on Arqade, but then reconsidered as it seems like primarily a Linux desktop environment issue more than a "game" issue per se, though no trouble using FireFox for other more traditional browser usage occurs, and, in fact, one can browse to other `https` sites on the `www.lotro.com` domain with no issue.  One cannot directly open the LOTRO Store link however.  The game client does something that one is unable to do manually; this is true whether or not the in-game store browser fails or not.

Helpful thoughts on how to debug KIO Client issues could be appreciated along with any wisdom one might provide about how one might go about troubleshooting and getting to the bottom of what might be wrong.

```
plasma-desktop-5.15.4-1.mga7
kio-5.57.0-1.mga7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet searches for `error kio client could not connect to host ssl negotiation failed` and/or `troubleshooting kio client ssl errors` turned up this question:

[Can't open links from Intellij: “Error KIO Client: Unable to create io-slave. Can not create socket for launching io-slave for protocol 'https'.”](https://askubuntu.com/q/1116344)
https://askubuntu.com/q/1116344

There seemed to be some similarity in that a third party application was trying to use web services, so it seemed worth looking into.

In fact, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1117526) helped point to a solution.  Essentially, the following was done.

- Start | Tools | System Settings | Applications | Default Applications | Web Browser

  - Default Component

    - (o) in  an application based on the contents of the URL

Changed to:

- Start | Tools | System Settings | Applications | Default Applications | Web Browser

  - Default Component

    - (o) in the following application:

      - Firefox

This fixed the issue, and the LOTRO Client now can open Firefox as it used to.

Reverting the setting back to its original value causes the problem to recur.